# How to separate `QObject`'s parent-child relationship's concerns, e.g. to interoperate with other owners?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr, qobject

Consider this use case: When a `QObject`'s lifetime is managed elsewhere, e.g. by the C++ scoped lifetime (as a local variable, or as a class member, etc.), or with a shared pointer, its parent should not attempt to delete it in the `~QObject()` destructor. Is there a way to truly pass the ownership of the object to the shared pointer, so that the parent won't attempt to delete it?

What may be the reasons for setting a parent if we don't intend ownership? That they exist follows from the fact that the parent-child relationship is appropriated for multiple purposes in Qt, and there's no built-in way to decouple them:

1. **[GC]** The parent acts as a garbage collector for the children objects: if any survive until parent's destruction, the parent will destroy and deallocate them.
2. **[Thread]** The child's thread affinity follows that of the parent.

   This was added to Qt 4 when `QObject` began supporting multi-threaded operation and gained the `thread` property.
3. **[WidgetTree]** Widgets use the parent-child relationship as an edge in the widget tree.

   - Except when the widget has the `Qt::Window` flag - then it is a top-level widget, and is a root of its own widget tree, but is still garbage-collected by the parent.

The immediate goal is to decouple the [GC] from other functionalities, and allow it to be disabled per-object. The extended goal is to decouple all three functionalities from each other.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

What you are asking for is equivalent to two `std::unique_ptr`s pointing to the same resource.

One is your C++ custom owner, the other is the `QObject` parent.

There is an intermediate solution though for half your problem: use `QPointer`. This class holds a `QObject` pointer, but is set to null if the `QObject` pointed to is destroyed. A custom `WeakQObjectPtr` type RAII class that holds a `QPointer` might then do what you want. This cannot though handle e.g. class members or local variables.

You're in the Qt world, live by the Qt rules, or don't use them. The latter is not always possible though.

Comment: Generally speaking, the “Qt world – Qt rules” follows mildly at best. Adding a flag to Qt that allows disabling of GC behavior is about 50 lines of text, including documentation comments that show up in qdoc output, so it’s not something ground-breaking in the Qt world. My main concern is doing it without changing Qt, as not everyone has a CI system that builds their product along with all the dependencies.

Comment: @Kuba I'd label "add a flag to disable out entire ownership model" quite (ground-)breaking in the Qt world. I'd bet tons of Qt internals magically either start leaking or stop working. Also: this is _not_ garbage collection. This is RAII, albeit not in the form of "modern" smart pointer-like classes.

Comment: GC is simply the release of an unreferenced resource - usually a memory resource, unless you add finalizers into the brew. So, I'd say that that's what QObject is doing, although it's sorta-kinda-half-broken. I wish they thought of a special factory method that would produce objects that are owned by a parent, and only those objects would be managed by QObject ownership model. Well, there's Qt 6 for that: but I have no idea yet how to do it without breaking source compatiblity. Incidentally, I am locally using the ownership-disabling flag and nothing breaks: I only use it on objects I own :)

Answer (score 2):

### [GC]

We can intercept the parent's `~QObject()` destructor and remove the object from the child list before the child objects in that list get deleted. Luckily, [`~QObject`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#_ZN7QObjectD1Ev) emits the `destroyed` signal before deleting its children.

Thus, to change an object's parent to a non-owning parent, we must take action only when it matters: when the parents' destructor gets invoked. Thus, we

1. Intercept parent's `destroyed` signal and clear the object's parent.
2. Intercept the parent losing the child, or, if the parent doesn't receive such events, intercept the events sent to the child and use them as a blunt hook to detect if the parent got changed.

This can be implemented in a free-standing utility function and a helper class, without the need to modify the code of any of the objects involved.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qobject-sep-concerns-55046944
#include <QtWidgets>

class ParentTracker : public QObject {
   QMetaObject::Connection connection;
   QObject *subjectParent = nullptr;
   inline QObject *subject() const { return parent(); }
   bool eventFilter(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event) override {
      qDebug() << receiver << event->type();
      if (receiver == subject()) {
         // Track parent changes on the child
         if (subject()->parent() != subjectParent) {
            detachFromParent();
            attachToParent();
         }
      } else if (event->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved) {
         // Track child changes on the parent
         Q_ASSERT(receiver == subjectParent);
         auto *ev = static_cast<QChildEvent *>(event);
         if (ev->child() == subject()) {
            detachFromParent();
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
   void lostParent() {
      subject()->setParent(nullptr);
      detachFromParent();
   }
   void detachFromParent() {
      if (subjectParent) {
         disconnect(connection);
         connection = {};  // free the connection handle immediately
         subjectParent->removeEventFilter(this);
         subjectParent = nullptr;
      }
   }
   void attachToParent() {
      Q_ASSERT(!subjectParent);
      subjectParent = subject()->parent();
      bool snoopChild = !subjectParent;
      {
         auto *widget = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(subject());
         snoopChild = snoopChild ||
                      (widget && widget->testAttribute(Qt::WA_NoChildEventsForParent));
      }

      if (subjectParent) {
         auto *widget = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(subjectParent);
         snoopChild = snoopChild ||
                      (widget && widget->testAttribute(Qt::WA_NoChildEventsFromChildren));
         connection = connect(subjectParent, &QObject::destroyed, this,
                              &ParentTracker::lostParent);
      }
      if (snoopChild)
         subject()->installEventFilter(this);
      else {
         Q_ASSERT(subjectParent);
         subject()->removeEventFilter(this);
         subjectParent->installEventFilter(this);
      }
   }

  public:
   explicit ParentTracker(QObject *child) : QObject(child) {
      Q_ASSERT(subject());
      attachToParent();
   }
};

ParentTracker *detachQObjectOwnership(QObject *child) {
   Q_ASSERT(child && (!child->thread() || child->thread() == QThread::currentThread()));
   QObject *parent = child->parent();
   if (!parent) return nullptr;
   if (parent->thread() != child->thread()) return nullptr;
   return new ParentTracker(child);
}

template <class T> void setup(QPointer<QObject> &parent, QPointer<QObject> &child) {
   parent = new T;
   child = new T(static_cast<T*>(parent.data()));
   parent->setObjectName("parent");
   child->setObjectName("child");
   Q_ASSERT(parent && child);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QPointer<QObject> parent, child, tracker;

   // parent-child ownership
   setup<QObject>(parent, child);
   delete parent;
   Q_ASSERT(!parent && !child);

   // parent-child without ownership
   setup<QObject>(parent, child);
   tracker = detachQObjectOwnership(child);
   delete parent;
   Q_ASSERT(!parent && child && tracker);
   delete child;
   Q_ASSERT(!parent && !child && !tracker);
}
```